# Geometric meaning of torsion in homotopy groups

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, geometric-intuition

It is not too hard to understand the geometric meaning of torsion in homology groups of CW complexes. However, I thought it would be interesting to hear how people describe/think of the geometric meaning of torsion in the homotopy groups of a CW-complex.

Comment: Incidentally, what is the geometric meaning of torsion in homology groups?

Comment: Scott: take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25865/the-word-torsion-and-its-connection-to-geometry-and-homology

Comment: @S. Carnahan:  Since the OP restricts his question to CW complexes, I suspect he has cellular homology in mind, whence torsion in homology is (reasonably) geometric, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the silly answer is that $f:\mathbb{S}^k\to X$ represents a torsion element of order $p$ if $p \cdot f:\mathbb{S}^k\to X$ extends along $\mathbb{S}^k \hookrightarrow D^{k+1}$ to a map $\varphi: D^{k+1}\to X$.

The slightly less silly answer --- the slightly deeper answer, that is --- is that, equivalently, $f$ itself extends to a map $\tilde f: P^{k+1}(p)\to X$.  Here $P^{k+1}(p)$ is the CW complex built of a point, a $k$-cell and a $(k+1)$-cell, where the $(k+1)$-cell is attached by a degree-$p$ map ${"p}$; and it's called the $(k+1)$th (cyclic) Moore space of order $p$.

For any $p$ the Moore spaces form a suspension spectrum $P^{k+1}(p) \simeq \mathbb{S}^1\wedge P^k(p)$, and there is in fact a long cofibration sequence
$$ \mathbb{S}^1 \overset{"p}{\to} \mathbb{S}^1 \to P^2(p) \to \mathbb{S}^2 \overset{"p}{\to} \dots $$
which gives rise to a long exact sequence of generalized homotopy groups
$$ \pi_1(X) \leftarrow \pi_2(X,p) \leftarrow \pi_2(X) \overset{p}{\leftarrow} \pi_2(X) \leftarrow \pi_3(X,p)\leftarrow \cdots $$
which in turn, for $n$ large enough, breaks up into the homotopy Universal Coefficient Theorem
$$ 0\leftarrow \mathrm{Tor}(\pi_n(X),\mathbb{Z}/(p)) \leftarrow \pi_{n+1}(X,p) \leftarrow \pi_{n+1}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(p) \leftarrow 0.$$

The letter $P$ is used here because, at least because they have also been called *Peterson* spaces, and maybe because $P^2(2)\simeq \mathbb{RP}^2$ is the real projective plane.

---

Note that I'm using the letter $p$ because when I worry about these things $p$ is usually prime, but that's not necessary in the above.

---

We give up continuing the sequence at the first $\pi_1(X)$ because, without more information, it's not clear that $({"p})_\sharp$ should be a group homomorphism.  Someone else can remind me what we can still say about the underlying sets.

Comment: I was told that the letter $P$ is used because these used to be called Peterson spaces.

Comment: Oh, that could be, too... mathematician often have poetic hearts, as well...

Comment: Funny fact: the univ coeff sequence does not always split. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46576/order-of-the-identity-map-of-a-moore-space/46585#46585

Comment: @Tom, yes, that's a fun one.  Recalling recent posts at the $n$-Cafe, this feels like further emphasis that the splitting is not *natural*. See particularly http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/03/homotopy_type_theory_ii.html#c037121